# How to render jsx only when a condition is true using react and typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to render a jsx if condition is true using ternary operator and using react and javascript.

what i am trying to do?
when the variable admin is true an count is < 0 i donot want to display the button "add". and should display under conditions below

```
admin && count > 0
!admin
```

below is my code,

```
render = () =>{
    return (
        <button> add </button> //should render this based on condition
    )
}
```

Could someone help me fix this. thanks.

**EDIT:**
below are the conditions to be displayed

```
count > 0 && is_admin
count > 0 && !is_admin
count <0 && !is_admin
```

condition when not to be displayed

```
count <0 && is_admin
```

Comment: In addition to the other answers, you can also use a guard and return `null` if your condition fails. e.g. `render() {if (!myCondition) return null; return <button>...</button>}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case, you can use short circuit evaluation:

```
render() {
    return (
      <>
        {((admin && count > 0) || !admin) && <button> add </button>}
      </>
    )
}
```

Comment: thanks but this will not display if it is not admin and count < 0

Comment: @someuser2491 Just double checked your question, and realised I missed out the other condition. I have just updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add "&&" to render conditionally

```
render = () => {
    myCondition && (<button>test</button>)
}
```